# Blender closes/crashes everytime I open and close a window

Tags: error, windows, installation, system

Since yesterday blender constantly closes/crashes everytime I open and close a window.
So far this happens on every window I have tried (e.g. file output path, file import, viewport windows, image textures)

[image: Example]

Better image quality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf3gp.jpg

So far I have:

Restarted the pc multiple times
Reinstalled Blender multiple times (via steam and manually)
Deleted all the Blender related files in Appdata and program files

Without any luck.

Hopefully one of you can help me.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

The guys over at blender told me what the issue was.

Turns out the problem is caused by my wacom drawing tablet. I uninstalled the drivers and now its working fine again!

Hope this helps someone!